# Log4j2 - debug-level logging except for Spring

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2

I'd like my application to run at Debug level, except for Spring, which is producing a huge amount of logging statements, which makes it hard to read through the logs. I've currently configured my Log4j2 file like this:

```
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="systemLog" fileName="C:/test/logs/system.log" includeLocation="true"
                    filePattern=""C:/test/logs/system-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} - %-5level [%t] %C %M %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="15 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <Async name="systemAsyncAppender" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="systemLog" />
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <SpringLogger name="org.springframework.*" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="systemAsyncAppender" />
        </SpringLogger>
        <Root level="debug" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="systemAsyncAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I thought that setting up the `SpringLogger` would set Spring to only run at ERROR level and, and write to the same log as everything else, but I'm still seeing full Spring DEBUG output. I have vague memories of being able to do this very easily with the old `log4j.properties` files (I think it was as simple as `log4j.category.org.springframework=ERROR`), but I'm not sure how to do this with Log4J2.

*(Using Log4J2 2.0.2, spring 3.2.11)*

Comment: I've not seen a `<SpringLogger>` element anywhere. Why don't you declare a normal `<logger>` with `name="org.springframework"` (note no `*`)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: `/facepalm` Yeah... that was it. For some reason I thought I needed to give the logger its own *element* name. Stooooopid! :P Your suggestions worked, so if you write that as an answer I'll give accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think log4j2 has any special configuration for Spring, so `<SpringLogger>` doesn't seem appropriate here.

Instead, just declare a regular logger

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="error" additivity="false">
    ...
</logger>
```

Also note the logger name. These are hierarchical. You don't need the `*` (and I *think* it actually breaks it).